# Kerberos authentication in IBM tm1 servers

Tags: java, kerberos

we are trying to generate a token using kerberos authentication for accessing IBM cognos TM1 Rest API.

BY using the below code, user principal name alone being retrieved. Token is not being generated and we are getting the below exception

GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)

**Java Code**

```
package Test;

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOError; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.PrintStream; 
import java.security.Principal; 
import java.security.PrivilegedAction; 
import java.util.Set;

import javax.security.auth.Subject; 
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext; 
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext; 
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential; 
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSException;
 import org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager; 
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSName; 
import org.ietf.jgss.Oid;

import com.sun.security.auth.callback.DialogCallbackHandler;

public class KerberosLoginTicketNew {


      private static Subject subject;
      private byte[] serviceTicket;

      private static byte[] token;

      static public String retrieveTicket(
           final String realm,
           final String kdc,
           final String applicationPrincipal)
   throws GSSException, LoginException
   {
 final File jaasConfFile;
       try
       {
           jaasConfFile = File.createTempFile("jaas.conf", null);
           final PrintStream bos = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(jaasConfFile));
           bos.print(String.format(
                   "Krb5LoginContext { com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required refreshKrb5Config=true useTicketCache=true debug=true ; };"
           ));
           bos.close();
           jaasConfFile.deleteOnExit();
       }
       catch (final IOException ex)
       {
           throw new IOError(ex);
       }

       // set the properties

       System.setProperty( "sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
       System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", realm);
       System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", kdc);
       System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config",jaasConfFile.getAbsolutePath());

       // get the Subject(), i.e. the current user under Windows
        Subject subject = new Subject();
       final LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("Krb5LoginContext",    new DialogCallbackHandler());
     //  final LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("Krb5LoginContext", new DialogCallbackHandler());
       lc.login();
       // subject=lc.getSubject();


       // extract our principal
       final Set<Principal> principalSet = lc.getSubject().getPrincipals();
       if (principalSet.size() != 1)
           throw new AssertionError("No or several principals: " + principalSet);
       final Principal userPrincipal = principalSet.iterator().next();

       System.out.println("userPrincipal:: "+userPrincipal.getName());


       KerberosLoginTicketNew ticket = new KerberosLoginTicketNew();
       ticket.initiateSecurityContext(applicationPrincipal, userPrincipal.getName(), lc.getSubject());


     BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();            
      String encodedToken = encoder.encode( ticket.serviceTicket);
      System.out.println("The encoded token is"+encodedToken);

       return encodedToken;

   } 

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Coming");

        String ticket = null;
        try {

            ticket=retrieveTicket("realm_value","kdc_value","application_principal_value");

 } 
        catch (LoginException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (GSSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println("Coming1");
        System.out.println(ticket);

    }


private void initiateSecurityContext( String servicePrincipalName, String userPrincipal, Subject sub) 
              throws GSSException {

            final GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
            GSSName clientName = manager.createName(userPrincipal, GSSName.NT_USER_NAME);
            GSSCredential clientCreds = manager.createCredential(clientName,8*3600,new Oid( "1.2.840.113554.1.2.2"),GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);
            GSSName peerName =manager.createName(servicePrincipalName, GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE);
            final GSSContext context = manager.createContext(peerName, new Oid( "1.2.840.113554.1.2.2"), clientCreds, GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
            context.requestMutualAuth(true);
            context.requestConf(false);
            context.requestInteg(true);


          byte[] outToken = context.initSecContext(new byte[0], 0, 0);
          System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(outToken));
          context.dispose();


            // The GSS context initiation has to be performed as a privileged action.
            this.serviceTicket = Subject.doAs( sub, new PrivilegedAction<byte[]>() {
              public byte[] run() {
                try {
                     //GSSContext secContext =  manager.createContext(serverCreds); 
                  byte[] token = new byte[0];
                  byte[] finalToken;
                  // This is a one pass context initialization.
                  context.requestMutualAuth(true);
                  context.requestCredDeleg(true);                
                  finalToken = context.initSecContext( token, 0, token.length);
                  //finalToken = context.acceptSecContext( token, 0, token.length);
                  System.out.println("Final token generated :: "+finalToken.toString());
                  return finalToken;
                }
                catch ( GSSException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  return null;
                }
              }
            });



          }
}
```

Please assist us in generating the token for kerberos authentication .

Thanks